# PostBuild event stuck in infinite loop

Tags: c#, .net-core, csproj

I'm trying to define a `PostBuildEvent` that will publish the project and then build the docker image:

```
<Target Name="DockerBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Message Text="========== PostBuildEvent - Building Docker Image ==========" Importance="high" />
    <Exec Command="dotnet publish $(ProjectDir)\MyProject.csproj -c Release -o ./app/publish /p:UseAppHost=true /p:PostBuildEvent=" />
    <Exec Command="docker build -t myimagename ." />
    <Exec Command="docker image prune --force" />
</Target>
```

However, this seems to trigger an infinite loop of build events.

I'm aware that `dotnet publish` will also do a build, but I thought that the `/p:PostBuildEvent=` parameter would negate that.

How can I configure the publish command to skip the `PostBuildEvent`?

Comment: You can define variable to prevent executing some commands and set it value to true in dotnet publish command row. Target has condition attribute.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0):

`/p:PostBuildEvent=` sets the `$(PostBuildEvent)` property to `''`, which is very different from resetting the target `PostBuildEvent`*. See: [MSBuild CLI Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022).

I suggest adding a Condition attribute to the Target and setting that instead.

```xml
<!-- Target will run if RunDockerBuild is ''(default), 'true', or anything else. -->
<Target Name="DockerBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent"
  Condition="'$(RunDockerBuild)' != 'false'">
    <Message Text="========== PostBuildEvent - Building Docker Image ==========" Importance="high" />
    <!--
      Update /p:PostBuildEvent= to /p:PostBuildEvent=false
      so that it matches the new condition above.
    -->
    <Exec Command="dotnet publish $(ProjectDir)\MyProject.csproj -c Release -o ./app/publish /p:UseAppHost=true /p:PostBuildEvent=false" />
    <Exec Command="docker build -t myimagename ." />
    <Exec Command="docker image prune --force" />
</Target>
```

*: The target `PostBuildEvent` can be reset using `<Target Name="PostBuildEvent" />`.

Comment: Where does `$(RunDockerBuild)` come from in this example?

Comment: Actually, adding the condition `Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true'"` works for my scenario.  Since the subsequent build is run via the command.

Comment: `$(RunDockerBuild)` is something I made up, like a variable I declared. I then use it in my example for disabling that target